# Leftist Heap doesn't support DecreaseKey operation?

Tags: c++, heap

I'm studying data structure. When I read the chapter of heap, something really confused me. DecreaseKey's time complexity of the binary heap is O(lgn). However, I found somewhere on internet claimed that Leftist Heap doesn't support DecreaseKey operation. But I wonder why? Can't we simply treat leftist heap as binary heap to perform DecreaseKey?

Comment: This question is a much better fit for [CS](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) website. I'd suggest deleting this question and posting it on CS.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: thanks! I will do it